# How to calculate the best route?

Tags: php, algorithm

I have been interested in calculating the route between two location, but never needing to do it before now. How does Google map find the shortest route between two destination? I know how to calculate the shortest distance between two geo location, but how do they  calculate the route to take between the two destination?

Comment: Dijkstra is one way to do if you don't have heuristic on vertices. Here's an example on how dijkstra is used to calculate shortest path to go from one metro station to another. https://github.com/amirbawab/GraphADT#example-of-a-project-using-the-graphadt-montreal-metro

Answer (score 1):

This is done by reducing the problem to **[Shortest Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem)**

You basically have a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) `G=(V,E)`, where `V` is some set of junctions, and `E` is the edges (roads) connecting between them.

Then, you can invoke shortest path algorithms on it. The simplest one is [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) in this case, but you can use more clever algorithms as well, such as [A* Search Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), since you have heuristic function of "how close I am to the destination".

Comment: For the moment, Dijkstra's Algorithm looks good. I will give that a go. Thanks for that.